# MLflow Error while deploying the Model to local REST server

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, mlflow

> **System Details:**
>
> Operating System: Ubuntu 19.04
>
> Anaconda version: 2019.03
>
> Python version: 3.7.3
>
> mlflow version: 1.0.0

**Steps to Reproduce:** https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tutorial.html

**Error at line/command:** `mlflow models serve -m [path_to_model] -p 1234`

**Error:**
Command 'source activate mlflow-c4536834c2e6e0e2472b58bfb28dce35b4bd0be6 1>&2 && gunicorn --timeout 60 -b 127.0.0.1:1234 -w 4 mlflow.pyfunc.scoring_server.wsgi:app' returned non zero return code. Return code = 1

**Terminal Log:**

```
(mlflow) root@user:/home/user/mlflow/mlflow/examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine/mlruns/0/e3dd02d5d84545ffab858db13ede7366/artifacts/model# mlflow models serve -m $(pwd) -p 1234
2019/06/18 16:15:16 INFO mlflow.models.cli: Selected backend for flavor 'python_function'
2019/06/18 16:15:17 INFO mlflow.pyfunc.backend: === Running command 'source activate mlflow-c4536834c2e6e0e2472b58bfb28dce35b4bd0be6 1>&2 && gunicorn --timeout 60 -b 127.0.0.1:1234 -w 4 mlflow.pyfunc.scoring_server.wsgi:app'
bash: activate: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/bin/mlflow", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/models/cli.py", line 43, in serve
    host=host)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/backend.py", line 76, in serve
    command_env=command_env)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/backend.py", line 147, in _execute_in_conda_env
    command, rc
Exception: Command 'source activate mlflow-c4536834c2e6e0e2472b58bfb28dce35b4bd0be6 1>&2 && gunicorn --timeout 60 -b 127.0.0.1:1234 -w 4 mlflow.pyfunc.scoring_server.wsgi:app' returned non zero return code. Return code = 1
(mlflow) root@user:/home/user/mlflow/mlflow/examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine/mlruns/0/e3dd02d5d84545ffab858db13ede7366/artifacts/model#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the steps mentioned in the GitHub Issue [1507](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1507) (https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1507) I was able to resolve this issue.

In reference to this post, the "**anaconda/bin/**" directory is never added to the list of environment variables i.e. PATH variable. In order to resolve this issue, add the "**else**" part of conda initialize code block from ~/.bashrc file to your PATH variable.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/atulk/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/atulk/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/atulk/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/atulk/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

In this case, I added **export PATH="/home/atulk/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"** to the PATH variable. However, this is just a temporary fix until the issue is fixed in the project.

Answer (score 0):

export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/python/Python/2.7/bin
can be used when you are not using anaconda